# How to set EC2 tags on AWS Opsworks

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I've been using various community cookbooks to set up a stack.

I'm aware that AWS Opsworks sets some tags for you (stack name, layar name), but I need to set some tags myself.

There doesn't appear to be a way to set them through the Opsworks API, so I'll assume I need to use a cookbook/recipe to set them somehow.

Is there an existing method/cookbook to do so, or do I need to go and learn chef?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LWRP listed on : https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/aws - works. It will help you add in  recipe the tags required for specific instances. The LWRP is : aws_resource_tag

Comment: Great stuff, that'll do for now. I set up this in the end https://github.com/stuart-warren/chef-aws-tag